# Proving an Equality In General

Tags: logic

When I am given to prove an **equality**, am I allowed to assume the equality is correct, work with it and then get a correct expression such as:

$0 = 0$

or

$A + I = A + I$

and thus conclude that the initial assumption was correct?

I fail to see why this is wrong as I see an analogy with proof by contradiction, however my professor tells me I am not allowed to start with the equality.

Any clarification would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $p \to q$ is TRUE also when $p$ is FALSE; thus, having derived a true conclusion from a premise does not license us to conclude that the premise is true.

Comment: If you work with only "if and only if" statements beginning with the initial assumption, then yes you can

Comment: It is OK while one is fooling around to find out what's happening, in rough work that no one else will ever see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By your strategy we could prove blatantly wrong equalities. For instance, let's "prove" $1 = 0$:

1. $1 = 0$
2. $0 \cdot 1 = 0 \cdot 0$
3. $0 = 0$

by which point you would conclude that $1 = 0$! Obviously this is not correct.

Comment: Damn, my assumption was very bad then. Thanks for giving me the examples!

Answer (score 2):

suppose you start with $1=-1$ and square both sides then you get $1=1$ but that does not mean the original assumption is true.

Comment: I see, thank you very much!

Comment: @kevin001 however your argument can be used to prove a contradiction. i.e if you wanted to prove that $A \neq B$, then you can start by assuming that $A=B$ and get a contradiction such as $0=1$